# Is it true that $\sum_{i=1}^n \log (n/i) = o(n)$?

Tags: limits, time-series

Consider the following summation: 
$$A = \sum_{i=1}^n \log (n/i)$$
Is this summation of order small oh of $n$? (or  $A \in o(n)$?)

Comment: You have $A=n\log n -\log(n!)$. Now use Stirling's formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation